# Java repaint region errors

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, paint

This is the error that i get occasionally but it halts the working of the UI

Does anyone know how to solve it?

This error hangs the UI generally occurs when we do repaint or update UI.

```
     Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
            at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.paintRegion(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.update(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthPanelUI.update(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source)
            at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source)
            at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source)
            at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.RepaintManager$3.run(Unknown Source)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
            at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
            at 

javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1000(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: This  problem often occurs when tying to update the GUI outside the EDT. For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: This is a NullPointerExp.. Post your code where this exception is thrown

Comment: @VKSingla Take a look at the stacktrace: it only contains JRE-lib signatures so the OP can't show you any code where it occurs. Anyway, Andrew's advices are correct.

Comment: Happening _occasionally_ is another hallmark of EDT violation.